# What are the motivations for this use of `__slots__`?

Tags: python, slots

Working with [Sanic](https://github.com/channelcat/sanic/tree/master/sanic) (async web framework in Python), I was trying to add custom data to a request:

```
request.user = 'A nice user'
```

But I was not able to, `request` is of type `Request` and does not allow this.

Looking at the source code for the `Request` class:

```
class Request(dict):
    """Properties of an HTTP request such as URL, headers, etc."""
    __slots__ = (
        'app', 'headers', 'version', 'method', '_cookies', 'transport',
        'body', 'parsed_json', 'parsed_args', 'parsed_form', 'parsed_files',
        '_ip', '_parsed_url', 'uri_template', 'stream', '_remote_addr',
        '_socket', '_port', '__weakref__'
    )
```

Looking up the internet, this `dict` inheritance has been added through [a pull request](https://github.com/channelcat/sanic/pull/163) to allow attaching data to a `Request` object.

So the recommended approach is:

```
request['user'] = 'A nice user'
```

This is all fine, I understand how it works.

However, **I am confused by the usage of `__slots__` on this class since it inherits from `dict`.**

Another way to allow attaching data to this class' instances would have been to remove the `__slots__` altogether (then we could have done `request.user = ...`).

The way I understand things, one use of `__slots__` is to reduce the memory footprint of the object, preventing the creation of the `__dict__` attribute.

But if we are inheriting from a dictionary does this still make sense?

Doing some command line tests with `sys.getsizeof` suggests it does not, but I'm not sure I can trust these.

How does this approach to allow adding data on the instances (using slots, inheriting from `dict`) compare to:

1. Not using slots, not inheriting from `dict`.
   Would attribute access be slower (could not verify this in command line tests)?
2. Adding `'__dict__'` to `__slots__`, not inheriting from `dict`.
   [This answer on slots](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28059785/3914041) suggests it would give us the behavior we want.

Are there some other reasons why one would want to use `__slots__` and inherit from `dict` here?

Comment: `__slots__` avoids the overhead of an additional `dict` to store `Requests` attributes; the fact that it also inherits from `dict` doesn't change that.

Comment: I realize that, but does inheriting from dict not outweigh the gain of not creating the additional `dict`? Because we will still be creating a dictionary (the object itself!) if we inherit from `dict`.  
Probably my phrasing is non-optimal somewhere.

Comment: No, because without `__slots__`, `Requests` both *is* a `dict` and *has* an additional `dict`. You still probably want to keep separate the data that a `Request` *stores* and the data that *describes* a `Request` object.

Comment: "You still probably want to keep separate the data that a Request stores and the data that describes a Request object." --> Thanks, this sounds like a relevant motivation for this approach. I would list it in 'other reasons' though since it's not related to performance. 
I'm still not sure about the approach vs the 2 alternatives that I mention in the question.

Comment: could it be to freeze the attributes that can be assigned to Requests?  for whatever reason the implementation feels that is useful.